# How can we see how many times a particular video watch? (in php)

Tags: php, html, mysql, video

I have a database from which i retrieve a path of video in server and 'echo' this path in src of video element of html.I did all this thing in loop.Like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM videos");

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($query)){?>

<video controls width="320" height="264">

<source src="<?php echo $row['videoPath']; ?>" type='video/mp4' />

</video>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Q:Now i also want to see how many times a particular video is watched? How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

have you considered putting a field in your table to count how many times a video was ordered i believe that is the best way to accomplish what you want

Comment: But how could i do this? i mean how i code in php to check which video is clicked?

Comment: i think you can display links and thumbnails in your page and when the link is clicked it takes you to another page where the video can be played

Comment: if you don't want this behavior you can simply use javas Script and jquery with ajax to update your data base I don't know if there are better solutions

Answer (score 0):

Moneer Kamal is right, Jusst add an extra field in your DB that increments. You shouldn't use mysql as it is a security risk, Look into mysqli or PHP PDO for connecting to your DB.

Comment: But how could i do this? i mean how i code in php to check which video is clicked?

Comment: use a js onclick event to call an ajax script that adds 1 to the field in the db

Comment: but how i know that which video is clicked